# JSF rendered question

Tags: jsf-2, el

Is EL-parsing of children to elements with rendered="false" really supposed to be evaluated? This is causing me alot of trouble with null pointer exceptions and similar. Looking at the following example:

```
<p:tab title="#{userCompetenceController.getTreeName(3)}" rendered="#{!empty userCompetenceController.getTreeName(3)}">
  <xdin:competenceTable id="competenceBox3"
                        profile="#{userCompetenceController.selectedProfile}"
                        tree="#{userCompetenceController.getCompetenceTree(3)}"
                        maxHeight="500px"/>
</p:tab>
```

The main issue (besides performance) is that `xdin:competenceTable` does not support a null `tree`-attribute. `getTreeName(int index)` returns null in this case, and is followed by a call to `getCompetenceTree(3)` which returns null, even though its parent (`p:tab`) has `rendered="false"`

In short: `xdin:competenceTable` is parsed by EL even though it's parent has `rendered="false"`. Why?

Comment: One thing that springs to mind - if you're using Facelets and the type of the attribute is not `ValueExpression` then the expression may be evaluated at tree creation time.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not knowledgeable enough to get your hint.

Comment: common view technologies are either Facelets (XHTML) or JSPs - they behave differently with respect to EL. In terms of attribute types - if you take an example like [panelGroup](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/panelGroup.html), most are defined as type `javax.el.ValueExpression` - this means they can take deferred expressions.

Comment: Makes sense. I assume the primefaces components I use are using ValueExpressions, so the whole tree is built without knowing if it should be rendered or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the JSF lifecylce below.

<s>Rendering is only the last phase, and `rendered="false"` only affects that last phase, while errors in constructing a component happen in the first.</s>

Non-rendered components *should* in fact not do anything during all phases, but it looks as though your component does not conform to that part of the spec.

[image]

Comment: Makes sense. So there is no way to conditionally parse EL-expressions?

Comment: @Rasmus: conditionally parse? Definitely not. Conditionally evaluate? Perhaps - not sure if && and || are short-circuiting in EL. But I wouldn't put too much logic into EL anyway and prefer to add methods to the backing bean.

Comment: My issue is not really with heavy EL logic, but with backing bean methods that lazily loads alot of data from a db. EL parsing of unrendered objects causes them to fetch data that is not needed yet.

Comment: @Rasmus: so couldn't those methods refrain from loading anything based on the same criteria you use for the rendered attribute?

Comment: Very true, but clutters up the code abit in the beans. I guess I don't have much choice though. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Michael - it is not true to say that the rendered attribute only affects the last phase - in a conforming component, it affects every phase - _Property: rendered. Access: RW. Type: boolean. Description: A flag that, if set to true, indicates that this component should be processed during all phases of the request processing lifecycle. The default value is “true”._ Components should check this value prior to processing at every phase. This is primarily a security mechanism.

Comment: @McDowell: Hm, so it looks like I was wrong, and the problem is that Rasmus' component does not follow the spec. Or would the EL of attributes have to be evaluated even in a conforming component?

Comment: @Michael - _deferred evaluation_ expressions are (or should be) evaluated lazily, so if a container is not rendered, no processing should take place that causes them to be evaluated. In this case, I do assume that the implementation of `p:tab` follows the standard algorithm for processing children and facets. _(There may be an exception in Facelets where the attribute is not defined to be of type `ValueExpression` - I think the expression will be evaluated at tree creation time in this case. I haven't done enough research to be sure.)_